# Aptana Studio 3.6 can't open Internet Explorer in Windows 8.1

Tags: internet-explorer, aptana3

I installed Aptana Studio 3.6 for my Tablet (Surface Pro 2 - Windows 8.1) and created HTML  project however, for some reasons when I run Internet Explorer I see actual HTML markup. How can I fix it ? I am not having this issue with other browsers only IE

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution... Take these steps 
Local Disk C/Users/Your Name/AppData/Roaming/Appcelerator - This is a default direction when you installed Aptana. What I did is I deleted Appcelerator folder, cleaned a computer and reinstalled Aptana Studio 3.6.1 again. Make sure to change visibility of the folder, make its settings visible so You can find AppData folder. That's it !